# Error 1109: expression expected in For cycle

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When I try to do this it gives me the expected expression error:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.sendersModel.length; i++ >){
      dataSeries.push({
        data: this.sendersModel[i]
      });
    }
```

Comment: What is that stray `>` supposed to mean?

Comment: That someone needs a better editor. A decent JS editor would have flagged it as bad grammar.

Comment: Scusate siete tutti Bill Gates capisco... le mamme vostre fanno le puttane evidentemente!